# Playground in Xcode cannot be opened

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I cannot create playground project, after I press `cmd+option+shift+N` or click 'Get started with a playground' shown like below picture, nothing happened. No window pop up, no any messages.

Can anybody help me to figure out why?

[image: xcode welcome window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, finally I found the below log in [Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_(OS_X)) app.

```
7/16/15 09:22:39.551 AM Xcode[1337]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7720/IDEKit/TemplateLibrary/IDEPlaygroundCreationHelper.m:48
Details:  Could not find suitable playground file template.
Object:   <IDEPlaygroundCreationHelper>
Method:  +createNewPlaygroundFromTemplateInWorkspaceWindowController:platformIdentifier:withContextSetupBlock:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fab12514460>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

It said Xcode `Could not find suitable playground file template`, then I realized I had modified code templates several monthes ago, so I was going to delete them

> sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/

Then playground works! It maybe caused by incompatible template files.

Comment: I used `mv Templates/ Templates.1` in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` and that restored my ability to create a new playground using File > New > Playground.